# Hide soft keyboard on activity where no keyboard operation found

Tags: android, textview, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have a tab view with one Activity per tab, and when I switch from the first tab, which only shows a list with search(Edit Text), to the second tab, which has a TextView, the soft keyboard is still there. I want it to go away. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

```
       <activity
            android:name="YourActivityname"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAwesomeTheme" >
        </activity>
```

the another way is to force them to hide as like below.

put this code in your utils class to keep the code organized.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore exceptions if any
            Log.e("KeyBoardUtil", e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

And you can call this method as `Utils.hideKeyboard(your activity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
public static void hideSoftInput(View _v,Context _c){
    if(_v.getWindowToken() != null){
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) _c.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jusr paste this method in your class this will on touch method and soft keyboard hide

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            View w = getCurrentFocus();
            int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
            w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
            float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
            float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    return ret;
    }
```

put it for hide

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: where u put this method

Comment: in my class i put this

Comment: actually your edit text is being focus whenever u come in this activity if u want by defalut close it then see my edited ans

Comment: where i paste this code in first activity ,where i have listview and edittext...or in second activity where i used textview only

Comment: paste it where u dont want to soft keyboard

Comment: but in my second activity ... no edittext, only textview used.. so what i do for this statement(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this whenever u touch other than your defined fields the keyboard will vanish.

```
//to hide keyboard
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            View w = getCurrentFocus();
            int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
            w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
            float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
            float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

            Log.d("Activity", "Touch event "+event.getRawX()+","+event.getRawY()+" "+x+","+y+" rect "+w.getLeft()+","+w.getTop()+","+w.getRight()+","+w.getBottom()+" coords "+scrcoords[0]+","+scrcoords[1]);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One line answer for u it will work

```
yourtextview.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES);
```